# Repair bad sectors and mbr in hdd

Tags: hard-drive, mbr

I launched `chkdsk`, suddenly my PC goes off, and my HDD was damaged !

I have 3 partitions (including the system-reserved one ) I can't access the root one (where win8 was installed and where I have my important files ), even, while installing a new system, the installation program goes off when it try to scan my HW configuration.

After a lot of work I recovered my data and I formatted those 3 partitions. I tried to reinstall win8 and I had some errors while copying system files, I tried to reinstall it several time, after that, and the installation program couldn't be launched.

This morning I tried a physical format and I canceled it in 3%. Now I can access the installation program but I can't partition my HDD.

I wonder if the hdd's mbr is damaged or I have some bad sectors ( because I had some problems while copying my files and this is why I ran `chkdsk` )

Comment: Since you have your data, your next step is to test the drive for bad sectors as @Athomsfere stated.  http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT is a good one.

Comment: @jmreicha, HGST is probably OK for Western Digital or HGST drives, but you should use the MFG's utility if you intend to warranty another brand. Seagate for example will not always trust WD's utility and Dell (if you are warrantying through Dell) will sometimes not except anything but Dell's

Answer (score 3):

First, fixing the MBR and Bad Sectors are 2 entirely different things. Once can be fixed, one cannot.

The MBR is just the first set of instructions on the partition that hands the BOOT processes to the OS. Running fix MBR from the Windows disk will fix this.

Bad sectors, can only be hidden or ignored. When you search for bad sectors, the drive just marks those sectors as bad so that in the future it will not try to read or write to those sectors. If you have a couple, thats can be OK. If you have a lot of bad sectors, that's indicative of a bad drive and the drive should be replaced. Generally more sectors will fail, causing the chronic cycle of repairing...

You should find the diag utility for your hard drive and test the drive, if it fails warranty the drive or replace it.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer !

So the mbr is something appropriate to the OS !?

i'll check hdd's bad sectors and i'll comment u back later !

Comment: i chekd the hdd's bad sectors and i get :
Warnings    = 0
Bad sectors = 0

while wiping i get an error at 25 %
some tools return the following error: invalid block size (0 or 0)

Comment: Which utility gave you that?

Comment: some tools in hiren's bootCD !

Comment: Which one? There are many tools on that download, correct? The error is going to be at least partially application specific for how it reports what errors.

Answer (score -1):

For sorting out the bad sectors, my recommendation would be Spinrite. It costs $90, but it has a 30-day money-back guarantee.

[www.grc.com](http://www.grc.com)

Comment: Nothing can actually fix a bad sector though... At best it does a better job of masking the bad sectors long enough for a thorough recovery...

Comment: That depends on your definition of a "bad sector". Hard Drives are effectively massive statistical engines. Data is mis-read all the time, and is often corrected on the fly by the drive's electronics. Some errors are easily corrected, others require a little more work. Some are unrecoverable outside of a clean room, if you are lucky.

Spinrite claims to use several different techniques in the hope of getting "one good read" from the drive before remapping the data to a "spare" sector. Here are some of the methods that it uses.

http://www.grc.com/srrecovery.htm